# tar does not preserve owner and permissions even when invoked as root

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, tar

I am attempting to `tar` files from my hard disk to an external disk, both of which are `ext4` filesystems. For some reason, even when invoking `tar` as `root` on extraction (which should automatically enable things like `--same-owner` and `--same-permissions`), the extracted files and directories have the wrong permissions and are owned by `root`. The command I used was something like

```
# Using long options for clarity/verbosity
tar --create Stuff | sudo tar --extract --directory /mount/point
```

For example, even if `Stuff` is owned by me and has permissions `rwxr-xr-x`, it ends up being extracted with `root` as the owner and `rwx------` permissions. Explicitly giving `--same-owner` and `--same-permissions` options has no effect. Bizarrely, invoking the second `tar` (the extractor), as myself (i.e. not `root`) does preserve the permissions (albeit with my `umask` applied, but that is expected behaviour). What is going on here? .w.

Comment: I made a quick `ext4` formatted ramdisk as a test to try to reproduce this strange behaviour, but it only occurs on my physical `ext4` external disk. Did I mount it incorrectly or something? .w.

Comment: How did you mount it? If not mounted by root, or mounted with some options it can prevent correct recording of ownership.

Comment: I did a simple `sudo mount /dev/<disk here> /mount/point` (not an entry in `/etc/fstab`). I did the same thing with the dummy ramdisk to see if I could reproduce this behaviour, and I could not. It only happens on this physical disk, for some reason.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can confirm it's not the filesystem because I can manually set ownership and permissions using chown and chmod. Using GNU tar 1.30 on Ubuntu 20.04. I don't see the same problem on Debian even though it's the same version of tar.